# Conditional expectation, martingale convergence theorem, and inequalities

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation

I have the following question.

We have a random variable $X:\Omega \to\mathbf{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and a continuous function $f:\mathbf{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(X)$ and $X$ are both integrable. Introduce n-component partition of $\mathbf{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ by $\mathbf{X}^{(n)} = \{\mathbf{X}^{(n)}(k): k =1,\dots,n\}$ and assume the
generated sigma-algebra $\sigma^{(n)} = \sigma(\{X\in\mathbf{X}^{(n)}(k)\}:k=1,\dots,n)$ satisfies $\sigma(X) = \sigma(\cup_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \sigma^{(n)})$.

Then from the martingale convergence theorem and the continuous mapping theorem, we know that both random variables $E[f(X):\sigma^{(n)}]$ and $f(E[X:\sigma^{(n)}])$ converge to $f(X)$ almost surely.

My question is whether there exists a sequence of random variables $(Y^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} Y^{(n)}$ is integrable and $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y^{(n)} = 0$ almost surely such that
$$
|f(X)| + Y^{(n)} \geq |f(E[X:\sigma^{(n)}])| 
$$
and
$$
|E[f(X):\sigma^{(n)}]| + Y^{(n)} \geq |f(E[X:\sigma^{(n)}])| 
$$
holds???

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I believe your assertion that $f(E[X:\sigma^{(n)}])$ converges a.s. to $f(X)$, not without something like a continuity assumption on $f$.  For instance, if $\mathbf{X} = [0,1]$ and $X \sim U(0,1)$, I can use something like a dyadic partition so that $E[X:\sigma^{(n)}]$ is a.s. rational.  Let $f$ be the indicator of the rationals and you will get $f(E[X:\sigma^{(n)}]) = 1$ a.s. for all $n$ whereas $f(X) = 0$ a.s.

Comment: Anyway, what does $E[X : \sigma^{(n)}]$ even mean if $\mathbf{X}$ is merely an abstract set?  I only know what it means to take the (conditional) expectation of a random variable if it takes its values in something like a complete topological vector space.

Comment: Thank you Nate. Regarding your second comment: I have modified my question to set $\mathbf{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$. Regarding your first comment, I relied on the wikipedia article for Levy's zero-one law which only requires that $f(X)$ be integrable (I think). I also assumed that $\sigma (X) = \sigma (\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sigma^{(n)})$ which I'm not sure holds in your dyadic partition example (I'm not sure). See the answer to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458035/jensens-inequality-and-conditional-expectation

Comment: I don't see where Wikipedia says anything remotely like your assertion.  The statement about the $\sigma$-algebras is true in my example because dyadic intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$.

Comment: OK. I see where I misinterpreted the wikipedia article. You're right. Thank you. I will modify the question.